# How can I analyse the motion of plasma

Tags: image-processing, python, video-processing

I am currently attempting a project of plasma analysis. One of the aspects of this project is to determine the stability of the plasma, when a plasma is unstable it loses its shape partially or starts bending.
Some examples [here](https://res.cloudinary.com/dgfemnerc/video/upload/v1670906967/Plasma_Motion_numkmi.mp4).

I have attempted to use `OpenCV` contours and `matchShapes` modules. The contours were able to be detected just fine however when the `matchShapes` function comes into play, the value for each picture barely differs.

I would like to get advice and be guided on how to proceed or if I should switch to a different method completely.

Comment: perhaps you can work with the squealing the plasma/apparatus emits? -- I'll work on the video for a bit...

Comment: I've got something based on "background subtraction". it responds to "changes" in the picture. the white dots here plot amount of changing pixels per frame from 100% down to 0.1% (logarithmic scale). https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAglF.png you see in the first part it's still thrashing violently, but also the bgsub algorithm starting to adapt. at some point, the thrashing reduces noticeably, resulting in significantly lower scores.

Comment: here's a video of that: https://imgur.com/a/4dJFXmJ -- does that look useful?

Comment: from looking at that video, the method you use seems to outdone, the contour method. As it seems to be more accurate. I would like to understand how it is done.

Comment: are you satisfied with my explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below an algorithm that tries to find similar pixels within a certain area around a pixel. Calculated are similarities between a reference frame and the previous frame. Both bottom instances in the window. The similarity values in info text are just sums of the pixels within the images.
Pixel brightness, here blue, shows the distance to the next fitting pixel. The more blue the more differences and the more the plasma moved. I am not sure if this approach is of any use beside the other one but if anyone is interested, here is the code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2
import queue

# calc average/fps
class Average:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.size = size
        self.values = .0
    
    def __call__(self, value):
        self.queue.put(value)
        self.values += value
        if self.queue.qsize() >= self.size:
            self.values -= self.queue.get()
        return self.values / self.queue.qsize()

average = Average(10)   # average difference between current frame and reference frame
delta = Average(10)   # average difference between current frames


class AverageImage:
    def __init__(self, shape, size):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.size = size
        self.blended = np.zeros ( shape, float )
    
    def __call__(self, image):
        dark = image.astype(float) * (1 / self.size)
        self.queue.put(dark)
        self.blended += dark
        if self.queue.qsize() > self.size:
            self.blended -= self.queue.get()
        return self.blended.astype ( np.uint8 )




windowname = 'frame'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Plasma_Motion_numkmi.mp4')

frames = cap.get(7) # total frames
print ( "total frames:", frames )

cap.set(1, 400) # frame 400 as reference
ret, frame = cap.read()
reference = cv2.resize ( frame, (0,0), fx=.5, fy=.5 )

blended = AverageImage ( reference.shape, 4 )

cap.set(1, 50)   # starting frame



# calculate how much a pixel moved within an area
class PixelShift:
  def __init__(self, area=8, sample=0.025, limit=30, color=0):
    self.area = area     # area (in pixels) to find other matching pixels around a pixel
    self.sample = sample # downsampling of input images for better speed
    self.limit = limit   # color difference at which a pixel fits (0-255)
    self.color = color   # 0:blue, 1:red, 2:green
    
    dx = dy = self.area # create a sorted list of coordinates with first being [0,0]
    self.quad = sorted ( [ (x,y) for y in range(-dy, dy+1) for x in range(-dx, dx+1) ],
        key=lambda tup: tup[0]*tup[0] + tup[1]*tup[1] # the shorter, the better
    )

    self.colorscale = 255/(math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) + 1) # maximum possible color
    self.colors = np.array ( [ [ # colors accordingly to distance
        int(math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * self.colorscale)
    for x in range(-dx, dx+1) ] for y in range(-dy, dy+1) ] )
    
  def fit(self, a, b): # pythons abs fails on uint8 from numpy so we need to hardcode it
    return (a-b if a>b else b-a) < self.limit

  def __call__(self, ref, image):
    r = cv2.resize ( ref, (0,0), fx=self.sample, fy=self.sample )
    i = cv2.resize ( image, (0,0), fx=self.sample, fy=self.sample )
    out = np.zeros ( i.shape, np.uint8 )
    
    h, w, bpp = i.shape
    
    for iy in range (h):
      for ix in range (w):
        (ib, ig, ir) = i [iy, ix]

        for (dx, dy) in self.quad: # find best color
          rx = ix + dx
          if rx >= 0 and rx < w:
            ry = iy + dy
            if ry >= 0 and ry < h:
              (rb, rg, rr) = r [ry, rx]
              if self.fit (ib, rb) and self.fit (ig, rg) and self.fit (ir, rr):
                out [iy, ix, self.color] = self.colors [ dy + self.area, dx + self.area ]
                break
        else: # no pixel found
          out [iy, ix, self.color] = 255
    return cv2.resize ( out, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]) )

pixelshift = PixelShift()



old = cv2.resize ( frame, (0,0), fx=.5, fy=.5 )

while 1:
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  
  smaller = cv2.resize ( frame, (0,0), fx=.5, fy=.5 )
  image = np.zeros ( frame.shape, np.uint8 )
  w = int(cap.get(3))
  h = int(cap.get(4))

  image [ :h//2, :w//2 ] = smaller
  
  smooth = blended(smaller)
  
  thumb = cv2.resize ( smooth, (0,0), fx=pixelshift.sample, fy=pixelshift.sample )
  image [ :h//2, w//2: ] = cv2.resize ( thumb, (w//2,h//2) )

  shifts = pixelshift ( old, smooth )
  old = smooth
  
  image [ h//2:, w//2: ] = shifts
  
  constant = pixelshift ( reference, smooth )
  image [ h//2:, :w//2 ] = constant

  text = f"frame: {cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)}"
  text += ( " similarity: %05.3f, similarity delta: %05.2f"
           % (average(np.sum(constant))*.00001, delta(np.sum(shifts))*.0001) )
  

  info = cv2.putText(image, text, (20,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
       (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
  cv2.imshow ( windowname, info )
  
  if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27 or cv2.getWindowProperty(windowname, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) <1:
    break   # escape or click on x

print ("closing...")
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The images are heavily sampled down to not slow the computer too much. Delta results between frames are much better then from the shape algorithm in previous post. Comparison between a reference frame has worse results.
If you want to use such a program to quickly turn down power if your plasma gets out of control this algorithm would be the better choice as it is a bit faster and more reliable on brightness changes.
If you got a pimp ass computer with 1000 cores you could put in several reference frames and choose the best one or trigger certain coils if the plasma moves too much left or right based on them.

The next step would be suppression of oscillation by comparing older frames. But my coding computer is too slow to test such things. If you want to do so you might want to remove the image smoothener I applied to the frames `smooth = blended(smaller)` or lower the value in `blended = AverageImage ( reference.shape, 4 )` which tells the pixel blender how much frames should be used.

Comment: The algorithm provided, is definitely an improvement, thank you for the advise and help. As of now i am not too concern with controlling the plasma just yet. Simply analying the stability and motion of the plasma.

Comment: The funny thing about this algorithm is: it is almost pure Python code with some Numpy and image resizing. Even the inner loop over `self.quad` is a simple Python iterator. No fancy calls to external C-code. Cython would optimize this really good.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your algorithm from your approach at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74771002/need-guidance-on-image-analysis?noredirect=1#74771002 a bit.

I don't know why they closed this question because basically only some smaller changes need to be done. There are 5 major points:

1. I changed your algorithm only around `matchshapes` calls, the rest is just formatting
2. The other suggestion, the pixel-march solution from Christoph Rackwitz will produce better, especially faster results.
3. Instead of finding just one good value from current frame you should use average over like 60 frames, hence the slow reaction quoted in 2. This was already mentioned in stackexchange comments. You need quiet an amount of input for `matchshapes`.
4. I multiply all similarities to get higher values for mismatches and lower values for matches than with sum or your min/max approach. This is basically the only difference between your algorithm and the one below.
5. Sometimes there are artifacts that need to be filtered. These are small shapes around small chunks of white pixels within the threshold. This might be the reason why your attempt failed. Seemingly it is a general `matchshapes` flaw and can't be fully avoided.

The huge disadvantage of this is the slow reaction time. In case you want to control your plasma somehow this might be bad. Second disadvantage is the use of shapes. If you have a brighter plasma, this attempt will possibly fail due to mentioned artifacts. I tried higher and lower threshold and the results weren't that good anymore. Anyway, here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

import queue

# calc average/fps
class Average:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.size = size
        self.values = .0
    
    def __call__(self, value):
        self.queue.put(value)
        self.values += value
        if self.queue.qsize() >= self.size:
            self.values -= self.queue.get()
        return self.values / self.queue.qsize()

average = Average(60)   # average difference between current frame and reference frame
delta = Average(60)   # average difference between current frames



windowname = 'frame'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Plasma_Motion_numkmi.mp4')

frames = cap.get(7) # total frames
print ( "total frames:", frames )

cap.set(1, 400) # frame 400 as reference
ret, frame = cap.read()
cap.set(1, 0)

reference = cv2.resize ( frame, (0,0), fx=.5, fy=.5 )


# https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

def threshold(image):
  grey = cv2.cvtColor ( image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
  ret, thresh = cv2.threshold ( grey, 50, 255, 0 )
  return cv2.cvtColor ( thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR )

# apply some filters
def outline(image):
  result = image
  grey = cv2.cvtColor ( image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
  ret, thresh = cv2.threshold ( grey, 50, 255, 0 )

  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours ( thresh, 2, 1 )
  cv2.drawContours(result, contours,-1,(0,255,0),1)
  return result

def contours(image):
  grey = cv2.cvtColor ( image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
  ret, thresh = cv2.threshold ( grey, 50, 255, 0 )
  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours ( thresh, 2, 1 )
  return contours

def similarity(ref, image):
  #result = 0.0
  result = 1.0
  level = 999.999 # ignore super high similarities (artifacts)
  for r in contours(ref):
    for i in contours(image):
      similarity = cv2.matchShapes ( r, i, 1, 0.0 )
      if ( similarity < level ):
        #result += similarity
        result *= similarity
  #print ( "  similarity: %2.3f" % (result) )    
  return result



old = cv2.resize ( frame, (0,0), fx=.5, fy=.5 )

while 1:
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  
  smaller = cv2.resize ( frame, (0,0), fx=.5, fy=.5 )
  image = np.zeros ( frame.shape, np.uint8 )
  w = int(cap.get(3))
  h = int(cap.get(4))
  
  image [ :h//2, :w//2 ] = smaller
  image [ :h//2, w//2: ] = outline(smaller)
  image [ h//2:, w//2: ] = threshold(smaller)
  image [ h//2:, :w//2 ] = outline(reference)

  av = average(similarity(reference, smaller))
  d = delta(similarity(old, smaller)) # delta values in change
  old = smaller

  text = f"frame: {cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)}"
  text += ( " contours: %02i/%02i, average: %05.3f, delta: %05.2f"
        % (len(contours(smaller)), len(contours(reference)), av, d) )

  print ( text )

  info = cv2.putText(image, text, (20,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
        (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
  cv2.imshow ( windowname, info )
  
  if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27 or cv2.getWindowProperty(windowname, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) <1:
    break   # escape or click on x

print ("closing...")
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This calculates basically 2 type of values: shape-change between current frame and the frame before. Shape-change between a reference frame, here frame 400.
During the first period, the values are low as the screen is black. Then values rise up to >1000 for frame similarity and around 200 for reference similarity.
Later both values drop to under 30. Where frame similarity drops even more.

For both value types a 60 frames average is calculated.

Comment: thank you for the assistance. Yep i am aware of the downsides of using contours with this methodology. I never thought of increasing the value to spot the difference. This was a eye opener.

Comment: I have no clue what you call "pixel march". I don't remember or see that I suggested anything resembling that description.

Comment: I got you wrong. I though about an algorithm like the one in my other post, that tries to find similar pixels from one image in another one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach based on "background subtraction". Background subtraction tries to "model" what is expected in the video (e.g. using gaussian mixture models), and anything out of the ordinary is "flagged" (resulting in a *mask*). One simple variant of that estimates one *mean* and *standard deviation* (one gaussian) per pixel, from a certain amount of previous video frames.

More on background subtraction in OpenCV (different models, their parameters): https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

The model will "get used to" what it sees. It will "flag" when the plasma starts but also when it stops (abrupt changes). Of course it will flag when the plasma moves in new ways. However, if the plasma moves in the same place, the model will eventually learn that and no longer flag this.

You can affect this through the "learning rate". Set it to non-zero when you see a stable plasma. The model will learn the appearance. Now set the learning rate to zero. Now it will always flag any differences to the learned model, no longer adapting to new appearance. I don't vary the learning rate here because I don't have the knowledge to judge what appearances of the plasma are "good" and "bad".

My approach uses one such background subtraction model and calculates a simple *mean* statistic on the mask output (fraction of "interesting" pixels).

You'll see the statistic being somewhat high while the plasma thrashes around. At some point, the plasma becomes stable. The statistic immediately drops down in magnitude.

You could calculate a more useful statistic from this one by taking the mean from a *moving window* of the per-frame scores. That will jump around less and be more indicative of ongoing "thrashing" vs. just singular changes where the plasma seems to "shift around" while being stable.

Basic operation (the rest is plumbing):

```
bs = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
for frame in video:
    fgmask = bs.apply(frame, learningRate=0.1)
    fgfraction = np.count_nonzero(fgmask) / fgmask.size
```

Output video of my script: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56GOz.jpg

(plotted markers, positioned vertically, represent change of 100% down to 0.1%, logarithmically)

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The complete script uses `imageio` for video reading and writing. You could also use OpenCV for that. Video writing is irrelevant to the operation of the script. The script also plots these values as they are collected. This plotting takes progressively more time. It is also immaterial to the operation of the *background subtraction* model.

The notebook: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/071e81e8c23475af4faa76144986fef9

Comment: This was explained really well, i looking into the methods and their strengths. It will take me awhile to read up and learn about this. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the suggested background subtraction by Christoph Rackwitz, you could just sum up the delta values and everything is code-golfed down to `sum(abs(old-current))`. However, comparing to a reference frame gets you the worst result. It still might be enough of a difference. Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

name = 'frame'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Plasma_Motion_numkmi.mp4')

cap.set(1, 400) # frame 400 as reference
ret, reference = cap.read()
cap.set(1, 50)   # starting frame
ret, old = cap.read()

while 1:
  ret, image = cap.read()
  
  text = f"frame: %i, similarity reference: %05.3f, delta: %05.2f" % (
    cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES),
    np.sum(abs(reference.astype(np.float32) - image)) * .000001,
    np.sum(abs(old.astype(np.float32) - image)) * .000001,
  )
  print ( text )
  cv2.imshow ( name, cv2.putText ( image, text,
    (20,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA
  ) )
  if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27 or cv2.getWindowProperty(name, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE)<1:
    break   # escape or click on x
  old = image

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The similarity values between neighbour frames which this algorithm provides, are really good and comparable to the other solutions.